# How to optimize 3's sum equal to k to O(N) complexity

Tags: python-3.x, big-o

My current approach is to start with left and right pointer, iterate i from left to right and find sum of 3, if its equal to target break the loop and exit else move the pointer till l<r this is leading to O(N^2) but need to do it in O(N):

Eg:

`a=[1,10,3,5,21,33,45]`

`target=18`

```
l=0
r=len(a)-1
flag=0
while l<=r:
    for i in range(l+1,r):
        if a[l]+a[i]+a[r]==target:
            print('-->',a[l],a[i],a[r])
            flag=1
            break
    if flag==1:
        break
    elif r==(l+1):
        r=len(a)-1
        l+=1
    else:
        r-=1
```

Output:
[10,3,5]

Comment: Your problem is not entirely clear to me: what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: to achieve the subset of array in combination of 3 to be equal to target value in O(N)

Comment: Are you sure this is even possible?

Comment: There are solutions a little better than O(n^2) as described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM . O(n) seems to not be possible, or at least known.

Comment: one of the interviewer asked me to optimize the solution in O(N) from above solution

Comment: Do input integers come from a specific range? Or can they be any number?

Comment: any number negative, positive or decimal.without any range